# mongoclient db.databaseName always returns admin

Tags: mongodb, node-modules

I'm using nodejs mongodb module v2.2.34

When I connect to a DB using this format:

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@MYATLASSERVER.azure.mongodb.net/mydatabase
```

db.databaseName always returns admin instead of mydatabase.

Why would this happen and how do I get it to return mydatabase as expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I found the solution

updated the driver to 3.5 and then used:
db.s.options.dbName

seems like a weird object path to get the name from

It's annoying that mongo keeps changing the paths of things with driver / version updates.  But I guess that's what we gotta deal with.  Feel free to post other solutions if there are more stable ways of doing this.  Or to explain why this change was made.